# Apache Nifi how to set up PutFile?

Tags: apache-nifi

I follow the step on page 21-26 from the book [Data Engineering with Python](https://www.amazon.ca/Data-Engineering-Python-datasets-pipelines/dp/183921418X/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3QW42IE3RCCEX&keywords=data+engineering+with+python&qid=1657869686&sprefix=data+engineering+with+python%2Caps%2C69&sr=8-1) to set up a data flow.

[image]

GenerateFlowFile Setting

[image]

PutFile Setting

[image]
Seems like some of the steps are missing. I can't find any folder in the `/opt` folder or any file in `/opt/nifioutput`. This is running on ubuntu 22.04

Comment: `Tasks/Time` for  `PutFile` showing `0` means it did not run! Check the configuration of the `SCHEDULING` and `SETTINGS` tabs if anything is missing. Also, check the content of any of the flowfile from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

PutFile processor is stopped. Make on it right click and choose "Start". If you observe any popup errors - read carefully, they may guide you to the missing configuration.